# How to store a number of a String-Arraylist to an int variable?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number and when you are finished enter '=' ");
    System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
    ArrayList<String> my_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String value = scanner.next();
    int num = Integer.parseInt(value);
    if (num == Integer.parseInt(value)) {
        my_list.add(value);
    } else {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number");
    }
    while (!value.equals("=")) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        value = scanner.next();
        my_list.add(value);
        my_list.remove("=");
    }
    System.out.println("The list looks like: ");
    System.out.println(my_list);
    backarryToNum(my_list);
}

public static void reverseArrayToNum(ArrayList number){
    int num;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = number.size()-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        int n = number.get(i);
        num = n * (int)Math.pow(10,i);
        sum += num;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

  }
}
```

The "int n = number.get(i)" line is the problem.

The method reverseArrayToNum will make the array reverse and will make the reversed array of numbers covert to a number.

Comment: Please define `is the problem`

Comment: What is `oning`? How one `ones` something? The title `How to one number of an arraylist to an int variable using get(index)?`

Comment: Don't use raw type. `ArrayList number` should be `ArrayList<String> number` and then this would be easier to notice that you want to parse a `String` in a `int`. Which is quite simple : [How do I convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change

```
int n = number.get(i);
```

to

```
int n = Integer.parseInt((String) number.get(i));
```

otherwise you try to store a String into an int.
Also, I suppose

```
backarryToNum(my_list);
```

is supposed to be

```
reverseArrayToNum(my_list);
```

Comment: fixed, thanks for the hint. i thought he jsut wanted to store the index

Comment: The casting could/should be prevented using the correct parameter type -> `List<String> number` . Since this list use a raw type, we need to cast but then could have problem receiving a `List<Integer>`...

Comment: i agree, however if we start talking about all the potencial flaws with his algorithm, we can just end up completely redesigning this.

Comment: Just the ones impacting the parsing, being the subject of the question. ;)

Comment: maybe so, i dont quite know where to draw the line yet.

Comment: sorry, no problem.